# Is it possible to generate a GitHub Copilot suggestion based on a natural language comment in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, github-copilot

The only examples in [the Copilot docs](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/getting-started-with-github-copilot/getting-started-with-github-copilot-in-visual-studio-code#generating-code-suggestions-from-comments) I see for natural language code suggestions are for javascript. Is it possible to do this type of thing with a Ruby comment?

```
// find all images without alternate text
// and give them a red border
function process() {
```

If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just what you're doing in JS and it should work. I just wrote the comment, it suggested the method name, I tabbed, it suggested the method body:

[image]